# Filebeat from docker host not able to harvest container logs with input.type container

Tags: docker, containers, elastic-stack, filebeat, elk

I have filebeat installed on our server where we run applications in container and the expectation is to ship the container logs to the remote logstash server which is configured and connection is tested and it works perfectly.

The problem I think is due to directory access. So below is my filebeat.yml -

```
- type: container
  enabled: true
  ignore_older: 48h
  recursive_glob.enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/lib/docker/containers/**/*.log
  fields:
    appName: some_api
  processors:
    - add_docker_metadata:
         host: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

The account by which filebeat is being executed on docker host machine doesn't have access to directory - /var/lib/docker/containers/**/*.log could this be a reason that logs are not being shipped.

If yes then what is the use of  input.type **container**, we could use the input.type **log**, right?

If no what else could be the reason? I have checked the container using docker inspect command and I am sure the log directory I have mentioned above is correct.